# Delegate and Events architecture with a Logger

Tags: c#, events, delegates

**Question:**  Is there a simpler way to architect this logging code using events?

Code inspired from @JonSkeets great talk on www.tekpub.com.  All errors in understanding are my own.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.GetDefaultName();
    }
}

public delegate void LogHandler(string message);

public class Person
{
    public void GetDefaultName()
    {
        LogEventRaiser raiser = SetupLogEventRaiser();
        raiser.OnLog("getting default name");
    }

    private static LogEventRaiser SetupLogEventRaiser()
    {
        ConsoleLogger cl = new ConsoleLogger();
        ConsoleLogger2 cl2 = new ConsoleLogger2();

        //when delegate LogHander is called, run fileLogger.Logger method
        LogHandler handler = cl.Logger;
        LogHandler handler2 = cl2.Logger;

        var raiser = new LogEventRaiser();
        //wire up event called Log which is of type delegate LogHandler
        raiser.Log += handler;
        raiser.Log += handler2;
        return raiser;
    }
}

public class LogEventRaiser
{
    public event LogHandler Log;

    public void OnLog(string text)
    {
        LogHandler tmp = Log;
        if (tmp != null)
            tmp.Invoke(text);
    }
}

public class ConsoleLogger
{
    public void Logger(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleLogger: " + s);
    }

}

public class ConsoleLogger2
{
    public void Logger(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleLogger2: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: So much inspired from Jon, that you almost forgot the actual qs? ;)

Comment: :-) yes I was (and am) a bit nebulous in this question.  Just trying to get a feel that I've got the architecture about right.  Am trying to refactor and make simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information about what you need the logging for there can't be much said about the code. All kind of secondary requirements can change the design.

If you need some high performance/throughput you'll need some queuing of log messages so the code that's called won't block on the log action.
If you need high certainty that a log message is actually posted you'll need a feedback mechanism and 'lots' of error handling code.
If you'll use this for performance logging you might be even better of with a performance profiler.

I'd say Keep It Simple and go from there.

Comment: Thanks CodingBarfield - I've changed tack slightly and gone for a simpler interface based approach to future logging.  As you say, keep it simple.  Good thoughts on a queues.  http://www.programgood.net/2011/12/28/DelegatesAndEvents.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a logging framework like NLog (http://nlog-project.org/)?

It will allow you to separate logging and targets. No need to hard code the targets. It also has the advantage of logging levels and low CPU loading if the logging level is disabled.

Comment: Cheers Rob - yes I've used NLog before and liked it a lot.